# SPF Records - mechanism not recognized by this client. unknown mechanisms:

Tags: domain-name-system, spf

Having a bit of a problem with my hosting company rackspace cloud and SFP records. I asked them to updated it on there DNS. This is what they set it as:

seonky.com.  300  IN  TXT  "v=spf1 ip4:ubuntu a include:184.106.171.113 ?all"

However when I test it with gmail I get this:

Received-SPF: unknown (google.com: domain of noreplay@seonky.com uses a mechanism not recognized by this client. unknown  mechanisms: )) client-ip=184.106.171.113;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=permerror (google.com: domain of noreplay@seonky.com uses a mechanism not recognized by this client. unknown  mechanisms: )) smtp.mail=noreplay@seonky.com
Received: from MFP2 (localhost [127.0.0.1])

Any idea what I should tell them so that they will fixe it and not ask me to go generate another SFP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking to tell Google that they need to change their SPF checking client to work with your record?

I don't want to sound harsh here, but the blame is not with them, and you do need a new SPF record.

The `ip4` setting needs to be an IP address, and the `include` record needs to be a domain name.  Not sure what you're intending with your record, but something like this may be what you want:

`v=spf1 a ip4:184.106.171.113 ~all`

See the documentation [here](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax) for more info on what can go into these records.

Comment: I don't want Google to change, that would be silly. Just trying to sort out why it's not working. I'll give "v=spf1 a ip4:184.106.171.113 ~all" a try, then I'll go for "v=spf1 ip4:184.106.171.113 a include:seonky.com ?all" (correct??) if the mail keeps going into the spam box.

Comment: You wouldn't want to `include` the domain that the record's in.  That would create an infinite loop - which I'm sure most checkers will account for, but may invalidate your record in some cases.

Comment: Status is showing as passed so I'm guessing it worked. Thanks - Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of noreplay@seonky.com designates 184.106.171.113 as permitted sender) client-ip=184.106.171.113;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of noreplay@seonky.com designates 184.106.171.113 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=noreplay@seonky.com